# Can not access imported accounts in paypal development environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

just found that PayPal changed their Sanbox, now I need real PayPal account to develop.
Ok, I went to my real one, imported my test sandbox accounts into it. Then, I go to one of these accounts on developer.paypal.com, and click "sandbox site" link. I expect that it will go to sandbox site where I can log in with this test account. But instead after clicking the link I'm getting "please login to use PayPal sandbox features" message on paypal.sandbox.com, that has a link to developer.paypal.com, where I'm logged in already. So, I don't know any way to log in with my test accounts now. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue due to transition from old sandbox to the new site. You need to delete your cookies and re-login to access the sandbox site. Please note that IE has permanent cookies stored on file system that need to be deleted. Firefox or Chrome would work better than IE8.